# Limpiar un String en c++

Tags: c++, string

```
void limpiarString (string &stringParaLimpiar) {
  int tamanyoString = stringParaLimpiar.length();
  cout << tamanyoString << endl;

  for (int i = 0; i <= tamanyoString-1; i++) {
    if (isalnum(stringParaLimpiar[i])) {
      stringParaLimpiar.erase(i,1);
    }
  }
}
```

Yo estoy intentando crear una función para limpiar una frase que tenga tipo ('¿','?') u otros signos parecidos y me han dicho de utilizar la función isalnum, que te detecta si es número o no pero no se usarla muy bien
Y he usado un erase, para así borrarlo cuando detecte el carácter distinto.
Y no sé porque no lo hace bien ni nada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que me sale por consola cuando ejecuto una frase, la cuestión es meter simbolos como (¿,?,¡,!,$,%...) y que no me los devuelva

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bua, es verdad, lo siento os debería de dar más información

Comment: Yo que tú seguiría el consejo @Trauma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero que pasa es que estás haciendo la comprobación al revés:

```
if (isalnum(stringParaLimpiar[i])) {
```

Este condicional entrará en el modo borrar cuando el caracter actual sea **una letra o un número** y tu pretendes eliminar todo lo demás, luego debes negar la condición:

```
// opción 1
if ( !isalnum(stringParaLimpiar[i])) {

// opción 2
if (isalnum(stringParaLimpiar[i]) == false) {
```

Pero hay más:

- Cuando eliminas un caracter, los caracteres que lo suceden **se desplazan** una posición, luego, al eliminar un caracter **no debes incrementar i**.
- Dado que cada vez que eliminas un caracter el tamaño del string se reduce, **no puedes** usar `tamanyoString` o, si lo usas, debes decrementar su valor cada vez que eliminas un caracter.

El código una vez aplicados los parches:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < stringParaLimpiar.size(); /* no incrementamos por defecto */) {
  if (!isalnum(stringParaLimpiar[i])) {
    stringParaLimpiar.erase(i,1);
  } else {
    i++; // Incrementamos siempre que no eliminemos un caracter
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

isalnum retornará true o false, lo que debes hacer es comprobar que retorne false

```
if (isalnum(stringParaLimpiar[i]) == false)
```

de este modo solo eliminarás los que no sean letras ni números

Comment: No funciona y a parte el error es más con lo de borrar